# Amazon cognito: add / remove user from group in front-end usign react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How to list users on react front-end and add or remove from cognito group in the front-end too?

I need some kind of explanation and some guide lines  to do it with aws-react module.

some guide lines or pseudocode would help me so much.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below API documentation for listing users in Cognito user Pool.

Please use AWS Javascript SDK to achieve the functionalities. It would be great if the logic can be written in Node as RestAPI and call it from the React UI.

List user - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Delete User - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html

Add User To Group - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminAddUserToGroup.html